# Поиск элементов в doubly linked list java

Tags: java, list, список

Имеется doubly linked list (двойной связанный список?) в java.
Создается `linkedList list = new linkedList()`. Заполнен случайными значениями int, длинна может быть задана пользователем. Необходимо найти количество элементов, которые входят в интервал [-100;100]. Как организовать сам цикл поиска элементов более или менее понятно, а вот как достать значения элементов списка, чтобы впоследствии определить их принадлежность к интервалу?

Comment: .get(I) ? или даже for (Integer u: list) или я вопрос не так понял?

Comment: Когда я ввожу .get(), то программа жалуется, что "method get() is undefined.."

Comment: а for работает ? get - а да, в чистых списках нет, там только итератором пройтись.

Comment: А как правильно записать этот for? Сейчас у меня получается type mismatch - cannot convert from object to integer

Comment: @Marqiz, добавьте код коим пытаетесь задачу решить - так проще будет указать где что не так

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вот полный код. http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-doubly-linked-list/ Условно надо добавить еще один `case` с поиском количества элементов в интервале

Comment: @Marqiz, ссылка может помереть, так что лучше добавить код в вопрос чрез правку.

Comment: @Marqiz если такая ошибка, просто напишите (Integer)obj и всё, т.е. сделать явное преобразование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
for (Object num : list)
    if ((Integer)num >= -100 && (Integer)num <= 100)
        count++;
System.out.println("Всего элементов в заданном диапазоне: " + count);
```

---

```
int count = 0;
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    if ((Integer)list.get(i)>= -100 && (Integer)list.get(i) <= 100)
        count++;
System.out.println("Всего элементов в заданном диапазоне: " + count);
```

Никак их доставать не надо. Это в `map` значения хранятся внутри `Map.Entry`, а тут они ни во что не завернуты, лежат как есть. Просто у вас `List` не типизирован, хранит `Object`ы, которые еще нужно привести к нужному типу. Если бы у вас был `List<Integer>`, то не нужно было бы выполнять приведение типа, и не было бы ошибки.